# Using NSTimer in swift playground

Tags: swift, uikit, nstimer, foundation, swift-playground

I'd like to know how to use an `NSTimer` inside a Swift Playground. [This question has been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27262688/nstimer-scheduledtimerwithtimeinterval-in-swift-playground), but none of the answers actually answered the question.

Here's my Playground code:

```
import Foundation

class MyClass {

    func startTimer() {
        NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.5, target: self, selector: "onTimer:", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    func onTimer(timer:NSTimer!) {
        println("Timer here")
    }
}

var anInstance = MyClass()

anInstance.startTimer()
```

Instantiating `NSTimer` with [`scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSTimer/scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:) creates the timer **and** schedules it on the current run loop.

But the method `onTimer` is never called. Why?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First of all, your `onTimer` method have to be declared as `@objc`, or `NSTimer` cannot find that.

As for your question, it's because you haven't started the run loop.

To do that, `CFRunLoopRun()` is the simplest solution I think.

```
import Foundation

class MyClass {

    func startTimer() {
        NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.5, target: self, selector: "onTimer:", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    @objc func onTimer(timer:NSTimer!) {
        println("Timer here")
    }
}

var anInstance = MyClass()

anInstance.startTimer()

CFRunLoopRun() // <-- HERE!
```

---

For the sake of completeness, as @MartinR metioned in the comment, you can also use [`XCPSetExecutionShouldContinueIndefinitely()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Playground_Ref/Chapters/XCPlayground.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014789-CH1-SW3)

```
import Foundation
import XCPlayground
XCPSetExecutionShouldContinueIndefinitely()

class MyClass {

    func startTimer() {
        NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.5, target: self, selector: "onTimer:", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    @objc func onTimer(timer:NSTimer!) {
        println("Timer here")
    }
}

var anInstance = MyClass()

anInstance.startTimer()
```

In this case the Playground runs only seconds specified in the Timeline:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: ... or XCPSetExecutionShouldContinueIndefinitely()

Comment: @MartinR with `import XCPlayground` :)

Comment: That's incredibly simple, the `CFRunLoopRun()` line. It makes sense given how `NSTimer` was implemented.