# Using NSTimer to print to console in a playground

Tags: swift

Given the function "printTime" that prints 3 statements (H/M/S) what is the exact syntax for calling this function using NSTimer interrupts once per second?

Comment: We need for info. Please post code for printTime.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using NSTimer in swift playground](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29232334/using-nstimer-in-swift-playground)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import Foundation
import XCPlayground

class Wrapper: NSObject {
    static let formatter: NSDateFormatter = {
        let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
        return formatter
    }()

    class func printTime() {
        print(formatter.stringFromDate(NSDate()))
    }

}

let timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: Wrapper.self, selector: #selector(Wrapper.printTime), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

You need to wrap the `printTime` function in an object to send to `NSTimer`. The loop will end when you change the playground's code.