# Timer does not run in Swift 3.0 playground

Tags: swift, cocoa, nstimer, swift-playground

Working in playground with Swift 3.0 I have this code:

```
struct Test {
    func run() {
        var timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: false) { timer in
            print("pop")
        }
    }
}

let test = Test()
test.run()
```

But nothing is printing to console. I've read [How can I use NSTimer in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24007518/how-can-i-use-nstimer-in-swift) and most of the usage of timer that I've seen in answers and tutorials online involves a selector so I tried this:

```
class Test {
    func run() {
        var timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.4, target: self, selector: #selector(self.peep), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    }

    @objc func peep() {
        print("peep")
    }
}

let test = Test()
test.run()
```

Still nothing seems to print to console. If I add `timer.fire()`, then I get the console prints, but obviously that defeats the purpose. **What do I need to change to get the timer to run?**

**EDIT:**

So adding `CFRunLoopRun()` after I called the `run` method for my `Test` struct did the trick. Much Thanks to those who answered, especially @AkshayYaduvanshi (who's comment pointed me to `CFRunLoopRun()`) and @JoshCaswell (whose answer brought up the fact that I timer only works with a run loop).

Comment: "Working in playground" And that's the problem.

Comment: Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29232334/using-nstimer-in-swift-playground)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to start a run loop.

```
RunLoop.main.run(until: Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 3))
```

The timer doesn't do anything unless there is a working run loop accepting input. The program simply ends.

[`Timer` reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/timer):

> Timers work in conjunction with run loops. [...] it fires only when one of the run loop modes to which the timer has been added is running and able to check if the timer’s firing time has passed.

Comment: Thanks for the rapid response. I missed that in the reference, I have to do some reading and testing before I can be sure, but this seems like the problem cause I'm not using runloops at all.

Answer (score 25):

Your first version works if you allow the Playground to run indefinitely via `PlaygroundSupport`:

```
import Foundation
import PlaygroundSupport

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true 

let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 3, repeats: true) { timer in
  print("Timer Fired at: \(timer.fireDate)")
}
```

Adding a run loop manually also works, and might be needed sometimes, but in your case this simple instruction is enough to make the Timer work properly.