# How do I add a callback to a func that contains a dispatch_after()?

Tags: swift, callback, grand-central-dispatch

I want to dismiss an UIAlertView after a couple of seconds (without need of an 'ok' button).

After some studying I found that I could use dispatch_after as the delay to eventually dismiss the alert:

```
func delay(delay:Double, closure:()->()) {  
    dispatch_after(
        dispatch_time(
            DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
            Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))  // ...Int64.init() struct in Swift.
        ),
        dispatch_get_main_queue(), closure)
}
```

Source: [Using dispatch_after vs NSTimer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27262688/nstimer-scheduledtimerwithtimeinterval-in-swift-playground)

The above code works fine, but I would like to edit the closure to allow passage of a sender:UIViewController parameter.  This is where I'm getting confused.

The dispatch_after() format is:

> func dispatch_after(_ when: dispatch_time_t, _ queue:
>   dispatch_queue_t, _ block: dispatch_block_t)

Here is what I tried (which is **WRONG**):

```
func delay(delay:Double, closure:(sender:UIViewController)->()) {
    dispatch_after(
        dispatch_time(
            DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
            Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))  // ...Int64.init() struct in Swift.
        ),
        dispatch_get_main_queue(), closure:(sender:UIViewController) in {

        })
}
```

**Question:** how to I fix this to have a block/closure parameter containing a callback reference ('sender:UIViewController')?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do do not need to "pass" `sender` to the closure. You only need to reference `sender` inside the closure.

This is known as `capture`, and it is one of the useful things about closures. The closure will `capture` a reference to `sender` and take it with it. It's like magic.

So write the closure somewhere where `sender` is in scope. Reference `sender` inside the closure. Then, pass the closure to `delay` and everything should work fine:

```
func closeAlert(sender: UIVewController) {

    let closure: () -> () = { 
        doSomethingWith(sender)
    }

    delay(3, closure: closure)
}
```

Again, the secret is that the closure captures a reference to `sender` that gets carried along with it when the closure gets passed to `delay`.

Comment: Wow.  That is powerfully...nice!

Answer (score 0):

The following (*abridged*) code displays my Alert Dialog (without buttons) for a few seconds and disappears.

I was thinking of using NSTimer but learned that was unwise.  
Using Swift + dispatch_after() is truly the way to go.

```
showAlert(sender: self, withTitle: "No Blisses", withMessage: "You don't have any Blisses to show.", alertPurpose: .timed)
```

```
enum AlertPurpose:Int {
    case none = 0  // ...default: no alert button.
    case simple // ...generic OK response.
    case timed
    case startBliss
    case noVideo
    case createdHashtag
    case missingProfileImage
    case profileSaved
    case settings
}

func closeAlert(sender: UIViewController) {
    let closure: () -> () = {
        sender.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
    delay(3, closure)
}

func delay(delay:Double, closure:()->()) {
    dispatch_after(
        dispatch_time(
            DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
            Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))
        ),
        dispatch_get_main_queue(), closure)
}
...
...
...
} else if alertPurpose == .timed {
        closeAlert(sender as! UIViewController)
```