# How do I use the update function in Swift Playground

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, swift-playground

Using SpriteKit in Xcode projects, I am able to use the update function to update everything I need to in between frames.

e.g.

```
override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
}
```

How can I do the same thing in Xcode Playground?

I do not think that this is a duplication of [NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval in Swift Playground](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27262688/nstimer-scheduledtimerwithtimeinterval-in-swift-playground)

/// UPDATE ///

I have discovered that I can add a class and therefore override the class to get the update functionality like so.

Add this code before any other code eg

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

   import SpriteKit
   import XCPlayground

    class PrototypeScene: SKScene {

    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {

        print( "update"  );
        callFunctionOutsideClass();

    } 
    }

func callFunctionOutsideClass(){
}
```

The next issue is scope. How do I call a function in the body of the Playground from the update function I have overridden?

If I try to add any properties to the Class I get an error - 
**"error: class 'PrototypeScene' has no initializers"**

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of working code. Your class needs an initializer in order to set properties! Some classes need the `required init` like the one shown below (This is the case for SKScene)

```
import SpriteKit
import XCPlayground

class PrototypeScene: SKScene {

   var blah: String?
   var foo : Int!
   var boo = 2

   init(blah: String) {
    super.init()
    self.blah = blah
    self.foo = 1
   }

   required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
     super.init()
   }

   override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {

      print( "update")
      callFunctionOutsideClass()

   }


}

func callFunctionOutsideClass(){
}
```